# How can I make it scrollable

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(50),
        child: AppBar(
          flexibleSpace: Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              gradient: GlobalVariables.appBarGradient,
            ),
          ),
          title: Text(
            widget.category,
            style: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: productList == null
          ? const Loader()
          : Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 10),
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  child: Text(
                    'Keep shopping for ${widget.category}',
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),


SizedBox(
                  height: 170,
                  child: GridView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                    itemCount: productList!.length,
                    gridDelegate:
                        const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 1,
                      childAspectRatio: 1.4,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                    ),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      final product = productList![index];
                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.pushNamed(
                            context,
                            ProductDetailScreen.routeName,
                            arguments: product,
                          );
                        },
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 130,
                              child: DecoratedBox(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  border: Border.all(
                                    color: Colors.black12,
                                    width: 0.5,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                  child: Image.network(
                                    product.images[0],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                left: 0,
                                top: 5,
                                right: 15,
                              ),
                              child: Text(
                                product.name,
                                maxLines: 1,
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
```

I tried SingleChildScrollView in child but it didnt helped.

Code Image

[image: Code Image]

Comment: It is supposed to be scrollable  when you’ve more item thats goes outof screen

Comment: no, it is scrolling horizontally. There are many products added to it, when scrolled in horizontal direction.
scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal`, therefore it is scrolling horizontally. you can remove it or set to `scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,` on GridView.

```dart
 child: GridView.builder(
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical, //this by default
     padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
```

No need to provide fixed heigth, use `Expnaded` widget to get available height, follow this snippet

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 10),
          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
          child: Text(
            'Keep shopping for',
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: GridView.builder(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
            itemCount: 44,
            gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 1,
              childAspectRatio: 1.4,
              mainAxisSpacing: 10,
            ),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              // final product = productList![index];
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {},
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 130,
                      child: DecoratedBox(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: Colors.black12,
                            width: 0.5,
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          // child: Image.network(
                          //   product.images[0],
                          // ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 0,
                        top: 5,
                        right: 15,
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        "name",
                        maxLines: 1,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: tried it, not working

Comment: what is the parent widget, can you include sample snippet from scaffold

Comment: @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(50),
        child: AppBar(
          flexibleSpace: Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              gradient: GlobalVariables.appBarGradient,
            ),
          ),
          title: Text(
            widget.category,
            style: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),